# removing traling slash with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have gone through different thread here that had the solution but for some reason it doesnt work for me, the solution I found to remove the trailing slash was

```
# remove trailing slashes
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

but it doesn't work for me, below is my .htaccess code:

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?slug=$1&post=$2

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
</IfModule>
```

please lete me know how can I fix so that instead of `http://domain.com/about/` it works like `http://domain.com/about`

regards

Answer (score 0):

Your firs trule is working with traling slash :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?slug=$1
```

Try using this in your htaccess :

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?slug=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?slug=$1&post=$2 [L]

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
   php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
</IfModule>
```